# C# generic class as a generic parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

Here is my exemplary implementation of a factory producing required resources:

```
public abstract class Resource<T> where T : ResourceObject
{
    protected string path = "base";
    public IEnumerable<T> payload;
    public Type resType = typeof(T);

    public T GetFirst()
    {
        return payload.First();
    }

}
public class ImageResource : Resource<Image>
{
    public ImageResource () : base()
    {
        path = path + "/image";
    }
}
public class RemoteResourcesFactory : ResourcesFactory
{
    public static T Get<T>() where T : Resource<ResourceObject>, new()
    {
        T resource = new T();
        resource.payload = load(resource.resType, resource.path); //here is some logic with instance
        return resource;
    }
}
```

And when I try to use it the error appears

```
Image image = RemoteResourcesFactory.Get<ImageResource>().GetFirst();
```

`The type 'ImageResource' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'RemoteResourcesFactory.Get<T>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ImageResource ' to 'Resource<ResourceObject>'`

I am C# newbie an want to know where I failed. Or maybe it is overall architecture mistake

Comment: Try `public static T Get<T, TObject>() where T : Resource<TObject>, new() where TObject : ResourceObject`

Comment: what if I dont want to explicitly specify ResourceObject type in Get<T> method? Shouldnt ImageResource already inherit it?

Comment: No, see https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1349

Comment: @DmitryK. Seems like your code should work as long as `Image` inherits `ResourceObject`.

Comment: @Sasha It inherits

Comment: @DmitryK. Not sure I can reproduce your issue then. Would you mind providing a minimal code example with the rest of the definitions?